# Knitr doesn't align title and table properly

Tags: r-markdown

Consider the following reprex in rmarkdown

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "TestUser"
date: "19/05/2020"
output: pdf_document
---

#### **test table**
```{r, eval=TRUE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)
head(mtcars) %>%
  kable(format = "latex")
```
````

[image: This gives the following results]

How can do I prevent the title above the code chunk to be displayed next to the table?

Comment: I don't see what you're seeing.  I get the title before the code block.

Comment: Hmm weird, then it must be something in my options but I'm not sure what

Comment: Maybe you need to update packages?

Comment: Updated the packages but it doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

Just needed to put `kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position")`